# English 1950s sci fi movie where a man and a woman are on an alien spaceship that they control using cubes

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

Trying to find the name of an old black and white movie where a man and woman end up on an alien spaceship. The ship is full of cubes with kind of a horn out of the top. They plug caps into the cubes to learn how to operate and defend the space ship from an alien race. They fire missiles from a flimsy looking space ring at the alien space ships. At the end I remember them being transported back to earth. I can't seem to find anyone else who remembers this movie.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Did you see this in a theatre or on TV?  What country was it in?  Do the cubes have a horn on top, or is the ship that has a horn on top?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your description reminds me of "[*The Terrornauts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terrornauts)", a 1967 movie based on the novel *"The Wailing Asteroid"*, by Murray Leinster. The story involves a group of characters who receive a radio signal from space. After they respond to the call, an alien ship appears and transports them to a deserted space station, where they are required as crew to repel an invasion by a different, hostile alien race.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! That is the movie. I was way off in the year, and now that I see the picture I;m starting to remember more. Thank you!

Comment: David, sorry I saw this on television, and it was the cubes that had the horn on top.

Comment: @McBain007: You can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 0):

**[This Island Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Island_Earth) (1955)**

I don't remember the control cubes and can't find any pictures of them, but everything else fits with this classic movie:

- From the 1950s (though not black & white)
- A man and a woman are taken aboard an alien spaceship
- The spaceship fires missiles at alien spaceships
- After the battle, the man and woman are brought back to the Earth

In the images below, one of the spaceship's crew does wear a cap, though I can't tell if it is used to control the ship or missiles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Given that OP has already confirmed that it's 'The Terrornauts' that they were thinking of, this answer seems unnecessary

Comment: @Valorum: Since the OP didn't mark the above answer as correct, I didn't notice that he had accepted it. My bad.

Comment: Always worth reading the comments :-)